# Creating CheckBoxes dynamically in Winforms, but text not getting displayed

Tags: c#

[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] AnalyteNames = new string[]{ 
     "NA", "K", "CL", "TCO2", "BUN", "CREA", "EGFR", "GLU", "CA", "ANG", "HCT", "HGB" };

    for (int i = 0; i < AnalyteNames.Length; i++)
    {
          CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
          box.Text = AnalyteNames[i].ToString();
          box.ForeColor = Color.Black;
          box.Checked = false;

          // AnalyteListCheckBoxes was a CheckedBoxList
          this.AnalyteListCheckBoxes.Items.Add(box);      
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please include a picture of what the added checkboxes look like. Also, remove the `ToString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this [overload of Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z38x31c0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
this.AnalyteListCheckBoxes.Items.Add(box.Text, box.Checked);
```

Another solution could be to set the `DisplayMember` property so that the compiler knows what it should display. Then you could leave your code as it is and after the loop include this line:

```
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
```

Comment: why not get rid of `box` at all and put `this.AnalyteListCheckBoxes.Items.Add(AnalyteNames[i], true);`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you are probably correct. I don't know, may be OP want to use the checkboxes somewhere else also. Although it is not obvious from the posted code

Comment: @NagarajuKuricheti you are welcome, but Dmitry has a valid point. Why do you create the extra checkboxes? do you want to use them somewhere else? if not then simply put the string as items in there. All elements in `Items` will have a `Checked` property on their own

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to put `AddRange` instead of loop:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string[] AnalyteNames = new string[]{
     "NA", "K", "CL", "TCO2", "BUN", "CREA", "EGFR", "GLU", "CA", "ANG", "HCT", "HGB" };

   // Create checkboxes with provided titles
   // checkboxes will be unchecked by default 
   AnalyteListCheckBoxes.Items.AddRange(AnalyteNames);
 }
```

Please, notice that you should not add `CheckBox` items, but `String` since  `CheckedListItems` creates its items internally.